# KeyedHashAlgorithm de 512bits tiene 288

Tags: c#, api, .net, security

Estoy desarrollando una API en .NET en la que quiero hacer el servicio de Login y devolver un token de autenticación. El problema viene cuando me salta esta exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'IDX10720: Unable to create KeyedHashAlgorithm for
algorithm 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha512', 
the key size must be greater than: '512' bits, key has '288' bits. Arg_ParamName_Name'
```

Haciendo una búsqueda por internet vi que uno de los problemas puede ser de la arquitectura de la base de datos, la cual está en postgres y para almacenar los datos los tengo en `bytea`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El servicio se desarrolla correctamente hasta la función CreateToken antes del return:

```
        private string GetToken(string username)
        {
            try
            {
                Claim[] claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, username)
                };
                SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_appSecurityConfig.Token));
                SigningCredentials cred = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);
                SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(_appSecurityConfig.HoursTokenExpiration),
                    SigningCredentials = cred
                };

                JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                SecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Cabe destacar que la creación de la contraseña se hace con salting+hashing:

```
private void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            using (HMACSHA512 hmac = new HMACSHA512())
            {
                passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
                passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            }
        }
```

¿Por qué me puede estar pasando este problema?

Muchas gracias de antebrazo.

Comment: Ese error ocurre porque la longitud de tu clave no es suficiente, aumenta la longitud de tu clave a un mínimo de 64 caracteres

Comment: ¿Por longitud de la clave dices que tiene que tener un mínimo de caracteres? ¿A que debo usar otro algoritmo de hash? ¿Otro salt? ¿Qué concretamente debo cambiar?

Comment: Aumenta la longitud de tu clave, antes de usar tu hash quizás debas cifrar primero con base64, o un sha y después aplica entonces tú algoritmo de cifrado

Comment: A la noche lo pruebo y te digo. Gracia.

Comment: Hola podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La longitud de tu clave es insuficiente, esto se debe a que la clave escogida no llega a los **512 bits** requerido. **Un caracter ocupa un byte, y un byte son 8 bits**, por tanto tu clave debería tener al menos **64** **caracteres**, **64 * 8 = 512**. Te propongo un truco que debería funcionar bien: concatena tu clave original con su inverso, es decir si tu clave es **"Hola"** el inverso será **"aloH"**, y la concatenación sería **"HolaaloH"**, si tu clave original tiene **288 bits** ahora tendría **288 + 288 = 576 > 512**:

```
string tokenOriginal = _appSecurityConfig.Token;
string tokenInverso = new string(tokenOriginal.Reverse().ToArray());
string tokenFinal = tokenOriginal + tokenInverso;
SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tokenFinal));
// Resto del código
```

Otra cosa que pudieras hacer es usar **SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature** con lo cual tú llave requerirá una longitud de **256 bits** que es menor a tu longitud actual de **288 bits**. También podrías usar otra función de hashing al token y después aplicar tu cifrado sobre este hashing.